# Switching to another task

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I am attempting to automate a process and this requires controlling some non-Delphi windows. Specifically I would like a button to simply shift focus to the other app, virtually press F11, and return to Delphi. The other program is obscure so the easiest would be to emulate "alt+tab" for switching focus. I have tried many of the posted examples, but they have not yielded results.

Comment: Start by reading this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539.aspx  I've left the Delphi tag in the question, but really this question has nothing to do with Delphi. It's a pure Win32 question.

Comment: As documented in the link posted by David you will not be able to return to your application. Once you activated this other app you have played your final card. You should definitely try to solve this in another way. Start by investigating whether or not the other app provides an automation interface.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly like you propose: *emulate "alt+tab" for switching focus*, *virtually press F11*, *return to your program*. [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can place keyboard events in keyboard input stream. Be sure to read the documentation though for the conditions when it will fail, like UIPI, existing keyboard state etc..

Below is tested to make the background internet explorer window full-screen and then return focus to the application. Refactor it however you like:

```
var
  Inputs: array[0..1] of TInput;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@Inputs, SizeOf(Inputs));

  // alt+tab down
  Inputs[0].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[0].ki.wVk := VK_MENU;
  Inputs[1].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[1].ki.wVk := VK_TAB;
  SendInput(2, Inputs[0], SizeOf(Inputs[0]));

  // wait for the task switch dialog
  Sleep(100);

  // alt+tab up
  Inputs[0].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[0].ki.wVk := VK_TAB;
  Inputs[0].ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
  Inputs[1].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[1].ki.wVk := VK_MENU;
  Inputs[1].ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
  SendInput(2, Inputs[0], SizeOf(Inputs[0]));

  // so that we can deactivate
  Application.ProcessMessages;

  // press F11
  Inputs[0].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[0].ki.wVk := VK_F11;
  Inputs[0].ki.dwFlags := 0;
  SendInput(1, Inputs[0], SizeOf(Inputs[0]));

  // F11 up
  Inputs[0].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[0].ki.wVk := VK_F11;
  Inputs[0].ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
  SendInput(1, Inputs[0], SizeOf(Inputs[0]));

  // give chance to the application to go fullscreen
  Sleep(100);

  // alt+tab down again
  Inputs[0].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[0].ki.wVk := VK_MENU;
  Inputs[0].ki.dwFlags := 0;
  Inputs[1].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[1].ki.wVk := VK_TAB;
  Inputs[1].ki.dwFlags := 0;
  SendInput(2, Inputs[0], SizeOf(Inputs[0]));

  // wait for alt+tab dialog
  Sleep(100);

  //alt+tab up
  Inputs[0].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[0].ki.wVk := VK_TAB;
  Inputs[0].ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
  Inputs[1].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[1].ki.wVk := VK_MENU;
  Inputs[1].ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
  SendInput(2, Inputs[0], SizeOf(Inputs[0]));
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can use EnumChildWindows() from a form to get the HWND of the window you want to click or type something or anything and use SendMessage on it with the message WM_SYSKEYDOWN(in case you are using function keys, if not, use WM_CHAR or WM_KEYDOWN), that will problably generate a virtual key press on the window without needing to focus on it, if you want to focus as well, use the message WM_SETFOCUS